# How can I make IDLE the default editor for Python files?

Tags: xdg

If I double click on a Python file on my Gnome Classic desktop, it is not opened in [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29). How can I make IDLE the default editor for Python files?

1. I have tried to delete all the other programs that were being opened.
2. I have been looking through IDLE's properties.
3. I have been looking through the program's properties as well.

When I run

```
xdg-mime query default text/x-python
```

I get the output

```
gedit.destkop
```

I do have IDLE installed, and I tried to right click the file and open with an application. IDLE was nowhere to be seen. But when I go to my applications, and go to programming, IDLE is there, clear as day.

Comment: What happens if you just write `idle` manually as described in Gabor's answer? You can also try using the full path (open a terminal and run `type idle` to get it).

Comment: What's the output of `find /usr/share/applications/ -name "*idle*"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily associate the `.py` files with IDLE. You have to right click a python script, choose "Open with -> Other application", then choose IDLE from the list with the checkbox asking if it should be the default application ticked. I use XFCE, but Gnome's Nautilus should be similar.

[image]

Alternatively, there is a configuration file in your home directory which contains the list of default applications. You can access it on the following path:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

You can extend it with the following line:

```
text/x-python=idle.desktop
```

where `idle.desktop` stands for the desktop file of the IDLE version you would like to use, for instance `idle-python2.7.desktop` or `idle-python3.desktop` based on the python version you have to use.

NOTE:

Be aware of the permissions of your scripts. If it has the executable permission, despite the default application, your system won't open it in IDLE, as it will try to execute it.

Comment: Is the name of the program enough or do you need a path? The name might be enough of the right `.desktop` file is there I guess.

Comment: Ah, thank you kind sir... But i still seem confused... Im really sorry... I tried to open it using the different aplicatoins, but idle does not appear

Comment: @terdon The command is enough if it can be accessed from the `PATH` variable I think. 
@AmateurProgramer Try to use the custom command option to access IDLE, if it canned be done with Gnome, try the second option (edit the configuration file).

Comment: A couple of things here: 1. In Gnome 3 that option - the entry box where you can enter the name of an executable - was removed. 2. The entry in `mimeapps.list` should be `text/x-python=idle2.desktop` or `text/x-python=idle3.desktop` i.e. it has to point to a _desktop file_ not to an executable. Also, it has to be under both `[Default Applications]` and `[Added Associations]` and it has to be the first in the list, before `gedit.desktop`, e.g. `text/x-python=idle3.desktop;gedit.desktop`

Comment: There is no such a "Use custom command" in Nautilus on Gnome Classic (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: @don_crissti I have corrected my answer, thank you.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for the feedback! I won't correct that part, as you provided a more satisfying answer in a Gnome environment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is caused by the default installed idle → desktop association.

Nautilus, at least on my 12.04 Ubuntu (Classic Desktop), doesn't seem to have anything with which you can associated (new) commands with a certain filetype (as some Desktops/Browsers) and the list doesn't show idle at all,  even if installed via `apt-get install idle`:

[image]

You can get the screen by right clicking a `.py` file, selecting <kbd>Properties</kbd> then the <kbd>Open With</kbd> TAB, and then click <kbd>Show other applications</kbd> (going via the <kbd>Open With</kbd>  menu gets you the same result).

You have to correct the `.dekstop` file for `idle` by editing 
`/usr/share/applications/idle-python2.7.desktop` as root (you might have idle-python3.desktop, depending on what version of idle you installed).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IDLE (using Python-2.7)
Comment=Integrated Development Environment for Python (using Python-2.7)
Exec=/usr/bin/idle-python2.7 -n %f
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/python2.7.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

What is missing in the installed file is the `%f` at the end of the `Exec=` line. Add `%f` there and save. Then in nautilus, right click a `.py` file and navigate to the <kbd>Properties</kbd> and <kbd>Open With</kbd> TAB once more (you don't have to restart nautilus). Now scroll down and `Idle (using Python-2.7)` is a selectable option (either as  recommended application) or else first click it in the show other application list:

[image]

You can use <kbd>Set as default</kbd> to always open `.py` files with idle.